# Dummy Variables in Python SKLearn Logistic Regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am using logisitic regression in SKLearn to classify data into one of 5 classes. To train the data I have a matrix of observations `Y` and a matrix of features `X`.

Sometimes it is the case that my matrix `Y` will have no category 3 say. In this case when I call the `predict_proba(X)` method I would like to have a list of 5 probabilities where the 3rd entry is 0 (as there are no category 3 observations). Instead this probability is simply omitted and a list of 4 probabilities is returned.

How can I change the logistic regression object to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A multi-class label can be found using the `sklearn.preprocessing` module.

Reference:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#label-binarization

Answer (score 3):

`LogisticRegression` doesn't allow this, but its close cousin `SGDClassifier` does:

```
logreg = SGDClassifier(loss="log")
logreg.partial_fit(X, y, classes=np.arange(5))
```

`SGDClassifier` differs in its training algorithm and parametrization. If that's not ok, then you'll have to roll your own wrapper code.